# "ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2)" (Machine Learning)

Tags: python, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding, imputation, train-test-split

I'm coding a regression model and for some reason it gives me an error "ValueError too many values ​​to unpack (expected 2)" when fitting.

However, my x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test are in the correct order and seem to receive the correct values.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline, Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


lst_object = []
for columns, content in df.items():
    if pd.api.types.is_object_dtype(content):
        lst_object.append(columns)

lst_numerical = []
for columns, content in df.items():
    if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(content):
        lst_numerical.append(columns)


numerical_type = make_pipeline((SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy = 'median')),
                                   MinMaxScaler())

object_type = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy = 'most_frequent'), 
                            OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown= 'ignore'), 
                            MinMaxScaler())


transform = make_column_transformer((numerical_type, lst_numerical),
                                    (object_type, lst_object))


model = Pipeline(steps=[('transform', transform),
                          'model', RandomForestRegressor])

X = df.drop('SalePrice', axis = 1)
Y =df.SalePrice
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.2, random_state = 0, shuffle=True)


model.fit(x_train, x_test)
```

Comment: Can you give the full error code / stack trace to help better diagnose the issue?

Comment: You need to fit the model on your train data, so the input parameters should be x_train and y_train.